# How do I create a gradebook using dictionary and global?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am supposed to have good variable names and have meaningful docstrings for all functions you write

I am extremely confused on this and would love to have someone help walk me through some of it if possible. I think once I get a start I won't have much of a problem. What is wrong w/ my code?

```
gradebook = {}

#################
def assignment(kind, grade, weight = None):
    if not weight:
        weight = 1
    global gradebook


    if kind in gradebook:
        gradebook[kind][0] += grade * weight
        gradebook[kind][1] += weight
    else:
        gradebook[kind] = [grade * weight, weight]
##################
def total(proportions):
    average = {}
    for key, value in gradebook.items():
        if key in average:
            average[key] += value[0] / value[1]
        else:
            average[key] = value[0] / value[1]
###########################
    grade = 0
    for key in average.keys():
        if key in proportions:
            grade += average[key] * proportions[key]
    return grade
```

Comment: Decompose your assignment into singular tasks and solve each one in turn. You'll generally find if you've broken it down enough then all your remaining queries will already be answered on SO. Don't take offense if you question is closed. Broad questions like this one require a lengthy answer, that many users are unwilling to commit to. These specific question are never generally useful, so It means a lot of work for very little reputation gain.

Comment: Start by writing a driver program. That is something that uses your functions. Then from there build up and implement the functions to perform the required tasks. Your instructor may have given you one already?

Comment: It seems this assignment wants you to make an object GradeBook. You should make one.

Comment: @JahKnows can you check my code?

Comment: @Paul Rooney can you check my code?

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: If you don't do your homework, you'll fail your tests. If you have specific roadblocks, you can try asking about them here, but make them about your issue, rather than your assignment. If you need more help, contact your teacher or TA. From the site help: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: @outis I updated my code

Comment: @JahKnows i updated my code

Answer (score 1):

This should look like something you may want to start with. I am really unsure what the descriptions mean. The level of English is atrocious.

```
class Gradebook(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.gradebook = {}

    def assignment(self, kind, grade, weight = None):
        # If a weight was not supplied the assignment 
        # says we should assume it was 1.
        if not weight:
            weight = 1

        # Add the new assignment type if not in the dic yet     
        if kind not in self.gradebook:
            self.gradebook.update({kind: [grade*weight, weight]})
        # Update the running total and add to the cumm weight 
        else:
            pass

    def total(self, proportions):
        pass
```